How to perform calculation based on multiple tables?
I have 2 tables in an Oracle database. The first one is KEY_SCRIPT which stores something called 'keys' along with their value:



ID
KEY_NUMBER
KEY_VALUE




A
1
11


A
2
6


A
3
5



The second table is WARNING which stores the information for the calculation to perform on the given keys:



ID
KEY_NUMBER
FUNCTION
LEFT_RIGHT
PRIORITY
ABOVE_BELOW
OPEN_PARENTHES
CLOSED_PARENTHES
OPERATOR




A
1
null
0
0
0
null
null
or


A
2
null
1
0
0
(
null
or


A
3
SUM
1
1
0
null
)
or


A
1
null
0
0
1
null
null
or


A
2
null
1
0
1
null
null
or


A
3
SUB
1
1
1
null
null
or



Mapping of the WARNING table:

ID: the unique ID for a group of keys in a calculation.
KEY_NUMBER: the keys used in a calculation, their values can be taken from the KEY_SCRIPT table.
FUNCTION: the operator between 2 keys. 'SUM' means '+' and 'SUB' means '-'
LEFT_RIGHT: '0' means the key is on the left side of the '=' in a calculation, '1' means the key is on the right side.
PRIORITY: the order in which a key is prioritized: 0 means first in order, 1 means second in order, 2 means third...
ABOVE_BELOW: '0' means the keys are on the FIRST PART of a calculation, '1' means the keys are on the SECOND PART
OPEN_PARENTHES: '(' indicates that there is a '(' in front of the key.
CLOSED_PARENTHES: ')' indicates that there is a ')' after the key.
OPERATOR: the operator between the FIRST PART and SECOND PART of the calculation.

I need to join both of the tables above and perform the calculation on a particular ID and after that, print out "right" if the calculation is true or print out "wrong" if the calculation is false.
From the tables above, I expect to perform the calculation:
key1 = ( key2 + key3 ) --FIRST PART of the calculation, where ABOVE_BELOW = 0
OR
key1 = key2 - key3     --SECOND PART of the calculation, where BOVE_BELOW = 1

If I substitute them with the KEY_VALUE from table KEY_SCRIPT, I will get:
11 = ( 6 + 5 )
OR
11 = 6 - 5

Which is true, I will need to print out "right".
I'm required to use PL/SQL on this problem. However, I don't know how to handle fields like: ABOVE_BELOW, PRIORITY, OPEN_PARENTHES, CLOSED_PARENTHES, OPERATOR and the cases in which there are multiple keys on the left side or multiple keys (more than 2 keys) on the right side (there are more cases of calculation in the original tables).
Can anyone help me with this problem?
On a smaller scale of the WARNING table, like this one:



ID
KEY_NUMBER
FUNCTION
LEFT_RIGHT
PRIORITY




A
1
null
0
0


A
2
null
1
0


A
3
SUM
1
1



I could write a query to perform the simple calculation:
DECLARE
    dy_id            VARCHAR2(10) := 'A'
    dy_left_value    NUMBER;              
    dy_right_value  SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;  
    dy_result        BOOLEAN;
             
BEGIN
    -- Fetch the left-side value
    SELECT KQ.KEY_SCRIPT
    INTO   dy_left_value
    FROM   WARNING WS
    JOIN   KEY_SCRIPT KQ
    ON   WS.ID = KQ.ID 
     AND WS.KEY_NUMBER = KQ.KEY_NUMBER
    WHERE  WS.ID = dy_id 
       AND WS.LEFT_RIGHT = 0;

    -- Fetch the right-side values 
    SELECT COLLECT(KQ.KEY_VALUE)
    INTO   dy_right_value
    FROM   WARNING WS
    JOIN   KEY_SCRIPT KQ
    ON    WS.ID = KQ.ID 
      AND WS.KEY_NUMBER = KQ.KEY_NUMBER
    WHERE WS.ID = dy_id 
      AND WS.LEFT_RIGHT = 1
    ORDER BY WS.PRIORITY;

    -- Evaluate the calculation
    IF dy_right_value.COUNT > 1 THEN
        dy_result := (dy_left_value = dy_right_values(1) + dy_right_values(2));
    ELSE
        dy_result := FALSE; -- Invalid setup if there aren't enough right-side values
    END IF;

    -- Output 
    IF dy_result THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sufficient');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('insufficient');
    END IF;
END;



There is no off-the-shelf solution for this. You have to write something to generate a stream of tokens and then use something like the shunting yard algorithm to convert it to reverse polish notation and then you can perform the calculation with the correct precedence.

You can generate the equations using LISTAGG fiddle - then it is just a matter of writing a parser in SQL to evaluate the equation (as per the linked duplicate).

Thank you for the answer. I have played around with LISTAGG for a while. It absolutely helps!
